# I am unable to run exec() on a file I just uploaded in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, permissions, imagemagick

I am uploading PDF files onto my Laravel public folder and I want to use ImageMagick to create thumbnails of the 1st page.
I am using the Exec() command through the process component (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html). However, I am getting an empty output.
Running the same command on my windows CLI requires me to raise the permission to administrator.
How can I fix this?

Comment: check logs, your server probably has disabled displaying errors, check php.ini for `disabled_functions`.

Comment: Actually, I found the silly mistake I was making is to continue using the Exec keyword in the command and then feed that command to the Process component. This obviously was invalidating my command. Now everything is running smoothly.